# Can not import Marionette

Tags: python, python-2.7, firefox, marionette, mozilla

When I try to import Marionette driver in Python, I get this response:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from marionette import Marionette
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_client-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/marionette/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .marionette_test import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_client-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/marionette/marionette_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    from marionette_driver.errors import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/marionette_driver/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from marionette_driver import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/marionette_driver/expected.py", line 8, in <module>
    from marionette import HTMLElement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette_driver-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/marionette_driver/marionette.py", line 20, in <module>
    from mozrunner import B2GEmulatorRunner
ImportError: cannot import name B2GEmulatorRunner
>>>
```

I have the Mozrunner package installed, but it does not have any B2GEmulatorRunner. Any suggestion as to what is causing this issue and how I can resolve this?

---

Edit:

After updating my entire Python 2.7 library with PIP, now I am stuck with this issue:

```
>>> import marionette
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .marionette_test import (
ImportError: No module named marionette_test
```

Comment: Which version of marionette and mozrunner are you using? Changes are you're using an old version of Marionette.

Comment: @Dexter I have these versions installed:
marionette-client    2.0.0       
marionette-driver    1.1.1       
marionette-transport 1.0.0
mozrunner            7.0.1

Comment: you should try to update then. Latest version is [2.7.0](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/d4b9e50875ad7e5d20f2fee6a53418315f6dfcc0/testing/marionette/client/marionette_driver/__init__.py#7) and B2G was removed since then.

Comment: @Dexter thanks, updating solved that issue, but now it says I don't have `marionette_test`

Comment: `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/marionette/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .marionette_test import (
ImportError: No module named marionette_test`